# SVM vector of weights

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, svmlight

I have a classification task, and I use [svm_perf](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_perf.html) application.

The question is having trained the model I wonder whether it's possible to get the weight of the features.

There is an **-a** parametes which outputs the alphas, honestly I don't recall alphas in SVM I think the weights are always **w**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing linear SVM, there is a  [Python  script](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm2weight.py.txt) based on the model file output by `svm_learn` and `svm_perf_`learn. To be more specific, the weight is just `w=SUM_i (y_i*alpha_i*sv_i)` where `sv_i` is the support vector, `y_i` is the category from trained sample.

If you are using non linear SVM, [I don't think the weights coefficients are directly related to the input space](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/how-to-construct-the-feature-weight-vector-or-decision-boundry-from-a-linear-s/86551#86551). Yet you can get the decision function:

```
f(x) = sgn( SUM_i (alpha_i*y_i*K(sv_i,x)) + b );
```

where `K` is your kernel function.